# Push Docker Images into docker.io

Tags: java, docker

I am able to prepare a image , but cannot to push it into the docker.io account,
https://hub.docker.com/r/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/

> mvn package docker:build -DpushImage

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ gs-spring-boot-docker ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\ttahkarakaya.TCLL\Desktop\gs-spring-boot-docker\complete\target\gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ gs-spring-boot-docker ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- docker-maven-plugin:0.4.11:build (default-cli) @ gs-spring-boot-docker ---
[INFO] Copying C:\Users\ttahkarakaya.TCLL\Desktop\gs-spring-boot-docker\complete\target\gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar -> C:\Users\ttahkarakaya.TCLL\D
-docker\complete\target\docker\gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar
[INFO] Copying src\main\docker\Dockerfile -> C:\Users\ttahkarakaya.TCLL\Desktop\gs-spring-boot-docker\complete\target\docker\Dockerfile
[INFO] Building image docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker
Step 1 : FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
---> f8103909759b
Step 2 : VOLUME /tmp
---> Using cache
---> 36841e0d87cf
Step 3 : ADD gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar app.jar
---> 6ef1582aca5e
Removing intermediate container 0bfc9fcc8f60
Step 4 : RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
---> Running in 0793aea1556d
---> c4b8911cf071
Removing intermediate container 0793aea1556d
Step 5 : ENV JAVA_OPTS ""
---> Running in 1f0c5db71b84
---> f7d64cfaa34d
Removing intermediate container 1f0c5db71b84
Step 6 : ENTRYPOINT sh -c java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar
---> Running in dd555e3e3b89
---> b71f4b224bbd
Removing intermediate container dd555e3e3b89
Successfully built b71f4b224bbd
[INFO] Built docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker
[INFO] Tagging docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker with 0.1.0
[INFO] Tagging docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker with latest
[INFO] Pushing docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker]
db4ee565a05f: Preparing
1d63660fa197: Preparing
a27c88827076: Preparing
58f7b9930e4f: Preparing
9007f5987db3: Preparing
[WARNING] Failed to push docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker, retrying in 10 seconds (1/5).
[INFO] Pushing docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker]
db4ee565a05f: Preparing
1d63660fa197: Preparing
a27c88827076: Preparing
58f7b9930e4f: Preparing
9007f5987db3: Preparing
[WARNING] Failed to push docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1/gs-spring-boot-docker, retrying in 10 seconds (2/5).
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\ttahkarakaya.TCLL\Desktop\gs-spring-boot-docker\complete>
```

> POM.XML

```
<properties>
    <docker.image.prefix>docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1</docker.image.prefix>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

docker.io/ahmetkarakaya/repo1
        1.8

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <!-- tag::plugin[] -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                <serverId>docker-hub</serverId>
                <registryUrl>https://index.docker.io/v1/</registryUrl>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>

                <imageTags>
                   <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
                   <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
                </imageTags>                    
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- end::plugin[] -->
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem, repository name is my new image name, so I have to tag local image with the full reponame

$ docker tag local-image:tagname reponame:tagname
$ docker push reponame:tagname

for my example I have changed the following as it is

```
 <docker.image.prefix>ahmetkarakaya/repo1</docker.image.prefix>

 <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}</imageName>
```